# Edit action is not working properly for a custom module at admin on mageno 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, adminform

I am trying to implement a module in Magento 1.9. I am new to it. Edit action on the admin side is not working. Whenever I edit a field, the original remains the same and another entry gets created which is edited one.

Here is my save function

```
    public function saveAction()
{
    // check if data sent
    if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
        $model = Mage::getModel('tv_faq/faq');
        $model->setData($data)->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
        try {
            if ($model->getCreatedTime == NULL || $model->getUpdateTime() == NULL) {
                $model->setCreatedTime(now())
                    ->setUpdateTime(now());
            } else {
                $model->setUpdateTime(now());
            }
            $model->save();
            if(isset($_FILES['image']['name']) and (file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))) {
                try {
                    $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('image');
                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png')); // or pdf or anything
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/TV' ;
                    //echo var_dump($path);die;
                    $uploader->save($path, $model->getId().'.jpg');
                    $uploader = 'TV/'.$model->getId().'.jpg';

                    $model->setImage($uploader);
                    //echo var_dump($model);die;
                    $model->save();
                                // display success message
                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(
                    Mage::helper('cms')->__('FAQ Item was successfully saved')
                    );
        // clear previously saved data from session
                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);
        // check if 'Save and Continue'
                    if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array (
                    'faq_id' => $model->getId() ));
                    return;
                    }
        // go to grid
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                    return;

                }catch(Exception $e) {
                    print_r($e);
                    die;
                }
            }
            else {       
                if(isset($data['image']['delete']) && $data['image']['delete'] == 1)
                $data['image'] = '';
                else
                unset($data['image']);
            }

            // Mage::getModel('modulename/flatrates')->saveMultipleFlatrates($data, $model->getId(),$this->getRequest()->getParam('cat_id'));

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            return;
        }
    }
    //Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('tv_faq')->__('Unable to find item to save'));
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

and here is my edit function

```
public function editAction()
{
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('faq_id');
    $model = Mage::getModel('tv_faq/faq');

    // if current id given -> try to load and edit current FAQ item
    if ($id) {
        $model->load($id);
        if (!$model->getId()) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(
                Mage::helper('tv_faq')->__('This FAQ item no longer exists')
            );
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }
    }

    $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData(true);
    if (!empty($data)) {
        $model->setData($data);
    }

    Mage::register('faq', $model);

    $this->_initAction()
            ->_addBreadcrumb(
                $id
                    ? Mage::helper('tv_faq')->__('Edit FAQ Item')
                    : Mage::helper('tv_faq')->__('New FAQ Item'),
                $id
                    ? Mage::helper('tv_faq')->__('Edit FAQ Item')
                    : Mage::helper('tv_faq')->__('New FAQ Item')
            )
            ->_addContent(
                    $this->getLayout()
                            ->createBlock('tv_faq/adminhtml_item_edit')
                            ->setData('action', $this->getUrl('adminhtml/faq/save'))
            )
            ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('tv_faq/adminhtml_item_edit_tabs'));

    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are getting? Its created new row?

Comment: yes.two fields of the same name are getting created. First one is original and another is edited

Comment: Did you create any primary key field like id?

Comment: yes. but I think there is a problem in saveAction function

Comment: Can you post your module files?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with **setData**, you need to call **addData** instead of **setData** in your **saveAction** like below:
Use

```
$model = Mage::getModel('tv_faq/faq');
$model->addData($data)->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))->save();
```

Instead of

```
$model = Mage::getModel('tv_faq/faq');
$model->setData($data)->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
```

Comment: I did this but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer,

```
public function saveAction()
{
    if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {

        // init model and set data
        $model = Mage::getModel('tv_faq/faq');
        $model->setCreationTime(Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate());
        $model->setData($data);
```